# How to select a specific method from a class in Route::resource?

Tags: laravel

I'am building my first laravel application.
And I have a question that I couldn't find anywhere else..

I have this block of code :

```
Route::prefix('/api')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('/buildings', BuildingController::class);
})
```

Does anyone know how to select a specific method in resource the BuildingController.
in the Route::get I'm using:

```
Route::get("/test", [Controller::class, "exampleMethod"])
```

But when I use that in a Route::resource it returns "Array to String conversion"

Any solutions?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution, u don't have to add the method u want to use because the laravel is very smart.
For example:

If u have a resource point **../api/buildings/1/edit**
the Route::resource knows that u want to edit the building with id 1

So u only need:

```
Route::prefix('/api')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('/buildings', BuildingController::class);
})
```

and in ur controller u need to create a method 'show' and that method will be called when u go to **../api/buildings/1**

you can get the default methods by creating a controller through artisan:

```
$ php artisan make:controller NameOfUrController
```

**Examples** : https://github.com/artesaos/laravel-docs/blob/master/controllers.md